# start executable without "open" cmd

Tags: command-line, osx, editors

I installed (using make...) a very interesting text editor called "aoeui" by peter m klausler on my OSx Mojave 10.14 
https://sites.google.com/site/aoeuiandasdfg/

I can start it in the terminal with "open aoeui" and work with it. However, 
I can't open existing text files as said in the man page by typing "aoeui (file)".

Typing "open aoeui [file]" starts aoeui AND opens bbedit to display the [file].

Is my installation missing something that I could call the app by only typing the app's name in the command line? (Same happened with other installations, like "wordgrinder" app.)?

Comment: In which folder does the `aoeui` binary reside? Is that folder in your `PATH`?

Comment: Does `open aoeui --args file` work?

Comment: If you want aoeui to be the default application, you'll have to use Finder to set that. Right-click the file, Open With -> Other..., choose your application and select "Always Open With"

Comment: @Panki: The aoeui is at the moment in "Downloads" (where I did the build).  It seems to be a "stand-alone" unix executable file. However, the README says: "To build, edit first few lines of the Makefile to reflect your system." <- I am not sure what this means.

Comment: @ Michael Homer: No.  Example: $ open aoeui -k notes.txt  (-k is for "Disable keyword highlighting)  - Results in error message: open: invalid option -- k

Comment: @ThomasD Place the executable under `/usr/local/bin` for example and make sure that's in your path, then you should be able to run it like you want.

Comment: @glenn jackman: Thanks, but I guess this is not the solution, as I don't click anything, I am just in the command line in the terminal. I tried your proposal, actually I cannot even select the `aoeui`  as an app. It has no file ending ".app". Adding ".add" isn't a solution either.

Comment: @Panki: Thanks great!!! This was the problem, now it works like a charm! Thank, Panki!

Comment: You're welcome my dude :)